# how to prevent an element going a bit up onhover/changing position afterhover

Tags: jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

I am creating a lazy load effect of social buttons with socialite.js
Everything is fine,however afterhover,the buttons go a bit upwards.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnkpH/)

```
CSS
/*
 * Socialite Look-a-like defaults
 */
 .cf:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
* html .cf {
    zoom: 1;
}
*:first-child+html .cf {
    zoom: 1;
}
/* visually hidden from HTML5 Boilerplate */
 .vhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
.social-buttons {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 00px;
}
.social-buttons > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 00px;
    float: left;
}
.social-buttons .socialite {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-4P_Yq4L-QXM/UTHWS6CDigI/AAAAAAAAGrU/t4K0HmWUv2U/s194/socialshare.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.social-buttons .socialite-loaded {
    background: none !important;
}
.social-buttons .twitter-share {
    width: 83px;
    height: 45px;
    background-position: -145px 0;
}
.social-buttons .googleplus-one {
    width: 65px;
    height: 45px;
    background-position: -75px 0;
}
.social-buttons .facebook-like {
    width: 77px;
    height: 45px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.social-buttons .linkedin-share {
    width: 59px;
    height: 25px;
    background-position: -215px 0;
}
</style>
```

I tried quite a few css tricks,but in vain.though I dont have much knowledge on jquery,i went through socialite.js and found nothing related to height afterhover.Is there any trick to make the position of element at the same place afterover.Thanks  a lot.

Comment: In which browser they go up ? Because in Chrome everything is OK

Comment: I'm using FireFox 19 and everything looks fine.

Comment: before 
http://img.ctrlv.in/5133081e9637f.jpg

after

http://img.ctrlv.in/513308486124d.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Firefox 19 on Mac and the plugins that replace the images do go up higher (if that's what you are referring to).

I tried just adding `margin-top:10px` to the `.social-buttons > li` and that seemed to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/NjuDa/

Comment: omg! i initially added padding top and didnt work,i had even tried margin top yesterday..at that time,the effect applied to the preloaded images..........anyways....thanks a ton!!

Comment: No problem! I was surprised the margin-top I added DIDN'T add to the preloaded images when I tried it... if it starts to push the preloaded images down, maybe just put a margin top on something like the iframe or wrapper div of the plugin.

Comment: compare this http://jsfiddle.net/fnkpH/ and http://jsfiddle.net/NjuDa/

the fear that margin top applied to preloaded images is true!

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nFVH7/ I did `div.socialite` instead, as it looks like the placeholders are `a.socialite`, so that applies the margin to the plugin but not the div.